# Installation package msi with check if the workstation is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

Installation package msi with check conditional "if the workstation is 32 or  64 bit

I need to make an installation package: which checks if the workstation is 32 or 64 bits and by finding. Next, if it is 32  go to  Share\Path\ and run the run.exe, and if it is  64 bits, go to Share\path and run the run.exe
I could do this in a *.bat, separate do 32.bat and 64.bat, but will be better to have one .msi with two conditional check, also I need to do this in Visual Studio or another language that  would give me a .msi, so I can send the .msi by sccm to my windows envirionment.

Could anyone help me with the code, please?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What toolkit are you using to create the MSI?

Comment: I am not a programmer, I have an .exe that a ex employee created for it but without the source code, so I tried to open the visual studio, knowing he has created in visual studio, but could not open.

Comment: You'll need to hire a programmer to replace him or learn yourself, sorry. Visual Studio cannot open `*.msi` nor `*.exe` files directly, only their source code (and you still need another toolkit to create MSI installers). MSIs are also not a tool to invoke another program, so using them just because SCCM supports them is inappropriate.

Comment: Thank´s Dai!! you can give me a hint where / site, I can start learning?

Comment: In all sincerity, undertake an undergraduate computer science degree course. While there are many practical "learn how to program" courses out there, they fail to teach the theoretical underpinnings, it's analogous to to teaching someone how to use a graphical calculator to make cool plots without teaching them the mathematics behind what they're doing.

Comment: Very practical response and void. Please do not over populate the article if you does not wish to help and snub only.

Answer (score 0):

You could build 2 installers one for 32bit, one for 64bit and create a SCCM application adding both those installers as deployment types.

Then for each deployment set the requirements to the operating system types that match.

Then you can deploy them both to the same collection and they will only run on the correct versions. (I am assuming you have one large collection you don't want to break down to x86 and x64 yourself) The others will report back as requirements not met.

Also if you are wanting this for an application catalogue deployment or user deployment same principles will apply. If they are on a 32bit PC the 64bit will not allow the install to start. (Quite possibly wont show on the list of available software)